# How to find similar records in ms access database compared to a specific record in the table

Tags: ms-access

I want to find the latest record of each patient and 
compare the columns of that record to another record of a specific patient ID
Bring out the similarities 
and group the records according to the percentage similarity value

So I want to see patients who have most similar records to that specfic patient to come on top and the rest follows.

[Patient record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3kCt.jpg)

Comment: Could you add any sample code you tried so far? Could you [edit] your question and add your data as text?

Answer (score 0):

In short, sort by a calculated variable.  Here is the query and table structure I used:
[image]

In my first definition of similarity I weighted each test equally:

CalculatedSimilarity: IIf([TestResults]![Test1]=[TestResult1],1,0)+IIf([TestResults]![Test2]=[TestResult2],1,0)+IIf([TestResults]![Test3]=[TestResult3],1,0)

in my second definition of similarity I doubled the value of the second test and ignored the 3rd:

CalculatedSimilarity2: IIf([TestResults]![Test1]=[TestResult1],1,0)+IIf([TestResults]![Test2]=[TestResult2],2,0)

to display as a percentage just divide by the weighted number of tests included.

When run against patient 5 who had "S" results on all tests the result is:
[image]

If you have many tests it would be better to construct the query with vba rather than the designer.  this next step gets around a designer bug by linking the query to normally invisible text boxes.
[image]

the combobox rowsource is set to:

```
SELECT Patients.PatientID, Patients.FirstName, TestResults.Test1, TestResults.Test2, TestResults.test3 FROM Patients INNER JOIN TestResults ON Patients.PatientID = TestResults.PatientID;
```

have the combobox set the invisible textboxes

```
Private Sub cmbPatient_AfterUpdate()
'access designer can't see the column property.  workaround by setting normally invisible text boxes
txttest1 = cmbPatient.Column(2)
txttest2 = cmbPatient.Column(3)
txttest3 = cmbPatient.Column(4)
similarity = cmbPatient.Column(5)
Me.Requery
End Sub
```

change the query parameters to reference the textboxes

```
CalculatedSimilarity: IIf([TestResults]![Test1]=[Forms]![Patients]![txttest1],1,0)+IIf([TestResults]![Test2]=[Forms]![Patients]![txttest2],1,0)+IIf([TestResults]![Test3]=[Forms]![Patients]![txttest3],1,0)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I am stuck with another question what if I want the user to be able to add extra tests to the column without the need of going into the query and adding a test column instead let the user  just select the test from lookup table. so how can I automate the procedure?

Comment: that is too complicated a question for a comment.  You should do what you can and ask another question. In short again, use the listbox.selected event and build the query with vba.  If the above answer helped you please upvote it or mark it as the answer.

Comment: Hi Mazula I had already figure out something similar to yours by just using queries only which made it long and impossible for a user to in future eadily add any more tests. Your soulution and my solution are just serving the present situation but will make the databse not practical in future. That's why I was hoping if you could show me a direction.